# Modal Image with HTML, CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I am currently trying to make an image gallery based on the code here: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

However, this doesn't work in the following structure. I added all the JS already, but still it is not working. Can anyone help? I added the JsFiddle at the bottom. Thanks!

```
        <section id="reflective" class="two">

            <div class="container">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="4u">
                        <article class="item">

                            <img class="image full myImg" src="https://www.royalcanin.com/~/media/Royal-Canin/Product-Categories/dog-medium-landing-hero.ashx" alt="W3Schools.com" />

                            <!-- The Modal -->
                            <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                                  <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
                                  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
                                  <div id="caption"></div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ohLbw3u0/

Answer (score 1):

Add **jQuery**, its a dependency here, you haven't added that.

Checkout updated **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ohLbw3u0/2/)**. Or have a look at the working snippet below:

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = $('.myImg');
var modalImg = $("#img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

if (img) {
  $('.myImg').click(function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    var newSrc = this.src;
    modalImg.attr('src', newSrc);
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  });
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal

if (span) {
  span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  };
}
```

```css
.myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.myImg:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content (image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}


/* Caption of Modal Image */

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}


/* Add Animation */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="reflective" class="two">

  <div class="container">

    <header>
      <h2>Reflective Journal 3</h2>
    </header>

    <p>Yes</p>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="4u">
        <article class="item">
          <img class="image full myImg" src="https://www.royalcanin.com/~/media/Royal-Canin/Product-Categories/dog-medium-landing-hero.ashx" alt="W3Schools.com" />

          <!-- The Modal -->
          <div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
            <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
            <div id="caption"></div>
          </div>

          <header>
            <h3>Ipsum Feugiat</h3>
          </header>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's work! Thanks! However, I created my own html, css and js files in my computer and copied the same code as above with correct jquery. When I opened the browser, it didn't work. Is it the browser problem?

Comment: @PeterWu No it shouldn't be, by the way which browser are you using?

Comment: Sorry for late replying. I tried to use Chrome and Firefox, but both couldn't work.

Comment: @PeterWu Can you host this code somewhere? So that I can have a look at the problem.

Comment: I copied the same code as above. And import the following files.

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/javascript.js"></script>

Comment: @PeterWu Didn't get you. Have you hosted your project anywhere?